# Why is my app showing unexpected token '{' import call expects exactly one argument . No stack on Expo go

Tags: react-native, expo

I keep getting this error on my expo go when I try to run an application I'm currently working on.
unexpected token '{' import call expects exactly one argument. No stack

I've tried re editing some imported statements

Comment: Can you show us the code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.